# Changing textures of objects in 3d model and rendering on server side?

Tags: javascript, rendering, 3dsmax, server-side-rendering, server-side-scripting

I have a 3D model (.max file) made in Autodesk 3ds max and I want to change textures of different objects by selecting from a list of textures on my website and get the whole scene rendered.

For example:  A room wherein I want to change textures of table, walls and floor by clicking on the tabs on my website. This can be done on the 3ds max software itself but I want to change it using texture tabs on my website by clicking the tabs, I guess it requires rendering on the server side itself.

How to go on with it, I as of now know HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery n PhP. Let me know if I need to learn anything else for this
One more problem here with the above is if I run Autodesk 3Ds max on server, this can be done if there is only one user. What if there are more users which will be the case and they try changing textures of different objects at the same time, is it possible?

Comment: You need to dive into WebGL (look up Three.js). You'll also need websockets for real-time communication between users (good luck with that with PHP... you'll need NodeJS or something similar). Collaborative real-time editing of 3D object in a browser is no trivial task at all....... but it can be done.

Comment: I have lot of irregularity in objects, how to select the objects and apply different textures to them in Three.js It seems we need to specify coordinates and I just have the .max file . 
Also by more users I mean, if more users try to do editing on their own in the same image, won't it overlap or am I going somewhere wrong.

Comment: This is a veeeery broad subject and a LOT of work ahead... way too much to get an answer in a comment or even in a response. Stackoverflow is here only to help you debug your code, not to build things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try diving into RealityServer. It is a product of a company called migenius, which works in real time on a similar concept - applying different materials in real time on 3D objects. [www.migenius.com](http://www.migenius.com)